# Error using Arabic Wordnet in nltk

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

I am using NLTK Wordnet for Arabic language. When I run the following code :

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
print wn.synsets('bank')[0].lemma_names('arb') 
print wn.synsets('ضِفَّة', lang='arb')0].hypernyms()0].lemma_names(lang='arb') #PROBLEM HERE
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nltk_wordnet.py", line 7, in <module>
    print wn.synsets('ضِفَّة', lang='arb')[0].hypernyms()    [0].lemma_names(lang='arb')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code assumes that word `'ضِفَّة'` will find a conceptual relationship using `synsets` and that the first item in the set will have hypernym(s). That may not be true. You can instead check if the results returned are non-empty before *indexing*:

```
word_synsets = wn.synsets('ضِفَّة', lang='arb')
if word_synsets: # False if word_synsets is an empty list
    word_hyp = word_synsets[0].hypernyms()
    if word_hyp: # False if word_hyp is an empty list
        print(word_hyp[0].lemma_names(lang='arb'))
    else:
        print('first item in ضِفَّة synset has no hypernym(s)')
else:
    print('synset for ضِفَّة returned no result')
```